# Angular 6: Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm trying to build a form but I get the "Form submission calceled because the form is not connected" warning.

Some inputs are deleted to make it more readable.

HTML:

```
<form name="newProduct" id="newProduct" (ngSubmit)="saveNewProduct()" [formGroup]="newProduct">
  <label for="productId">Id</label><br />
  <input name="productId" id="productId" type="number" formControlName="productId" placeholder="productId" autocomplete="off" />
   <m-spinner-button [options]="spinner" type="submit" (click)="modal.close()">ADD PRODUCT</m-spinner-button>
</form>
```

component.ts

```
  newProduct = new FormGroup({
    productId: new FormControl("")
  });

  saveNewProduct(){
    console.log(this.newProduct.value)
  }
```

What's wrong in here, it should be connected?

Comment: If you remove the click handler from the button and make sure it’s of type submit, do you get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

If your form is in a modal, then it looks like the click handler closing the modal is destroying/unmounting the form before it can submit. Update the button to remove the click handler. You can move the modal `close` into the body of the event handler if you want to close the modal after submission:

Template:

```
<form name="newProduct" id="newProduct" (ngSubmit)="saveNewProduct()" [formGroup]="newProduct">
  <label for="productId">Id</label><br />
  <input name="productId" id="productId" type="number" formControlName="productId" placeholder="productId" autocomplete="off" />
   <m-spinner-button [options]="spinner" type="submit">ADD PRODUCT</m-spinner-button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
saveNewProduct() {
  // ... your existing code
  this.modal.close(); // close the modal when everything else is done
}
```

Hopefully that helps!